# CSS 2 pictures full width in One Column

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to make it look like in this picture:

[image]

I am using wordpress and I still did not figure out how to make it full width.

I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance.

What I have right now:

[image]

CSS of the left picture:

```
#parallax887 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2048x1536-orange-red-solid-color-background.jpg") repeat scroll 50% 0 / cover ;
    min-height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}
```

CSS of the Picture on the right side:

```
#parallax887 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2048x1536-orange-red-solid-color-background.jpg") repeat scroll 50% 0 / cover ;
    min-height: 350px;
position: relative;
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle, or the whole code of divs that contains the 2 images?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/acsp5qq2/

Is this ok?

Comment: Please help. I need this :(

Comment: @Duy Please, fix your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you -*mistakenly*- duplicated the style for left & write image. But anyway you can achieve that like this:

1. Give both images `width: 50%;`
2. Remove *Margins*
3. The trick here is to remove *the white space* between the images that results from pressing `enter` or `space` after the first element

*for example you should either put your images like this* `<img /><img />` or

```
<img /><!--
commenting to escape white space
--><img />
```

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Flag_of_Afghanistan_(1880%E2%80%931901).svg/2000px-Flag_of_Afghanistan_(1880%E2%80%931901).svg.png" id="first" /><!--
--><img src="http://www.kurzon.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2048x1536-orange-red-solid-color-background.jpg" id="second" />`
```

**CSS**

```
#first, #second{
   width:50%;
   min-height: 350px;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

And here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/du36zj4j/).